# Android Notification not inserting into SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have been debugging this problem for hours and I have looked around and cannot seem to find a solution. When I run the code everything works fine except insertNotification is not inserting a new value into the notification table and no exceptions are thrown. Why is this?

```
public void updateLaw(int lawID, String newSummary, String newFullText){

    int tagID = getTagID(lawID);
    String tagName = getTagName(tagID);
    int categoryID = getCategoryID(tagID);
    String categoryName = getCategoryName(categoryID);

    openToWrite();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Constants.KEY_SUMMARY, newSummary);
        if(newFullText!=null)
            contentValues.put(Constants.KEY_FULL_TEXT, newFullText);

        mSqLiteDatabase.update(Constants.TABLE_LAW, contentValues, Constants.KEY_LAW_ID + "=" + lawID, null);
    close();
    try {
        insertNotification(categoryName, tagName + " has changed in " + getLocationName(getLocationID(lawID)));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        exceptionHandler.alert(e, "UpdateLaw()");
    }

}

public void insertNotification(String type, String text){

    openToWrite();
    try {
        mSqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notification");
        String tableQuery = "CREATE TABLE "+Constants.TABLE_NOTIFICATION+" (\n" +
            Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                Constants.KEY_LAW_ID + " INT,\n" +
            Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TEXT + " VARCHAR,\n" +
            Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TIME + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,\n" +
            Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_STATUS + " VARCHAR\n" +
            ");\n";
        mSqLiteDatabase.execSQL(tableQuery);
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        exceptionHandler.alert(e, "insertNotification()");
    }

    try {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TYPE, type);
        contentValues.put(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TEXT, text);
        contentValues.put(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_STATUS, "unread");

        mSqLiteDatabase.insert(Constants.TABLE_NOTIFICATION, null, contentValues);
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        exceptionHandler.alert(e, "insertNotification()");
    }
    close();

}
```

Comment: Bit confused at the time of inserting you dropping the table and recreating it another thing in notification table at the time of insertion you also not providing primary key column value

Comment: it was the key column value. I do that so I can start with a fresh table every time for debugging

Comment: Where are the `categoryID` and `tagID` variables coming from if you're not passing them in as arguments in the `updateLaw` method? How are the values of `categoryName` and `tagName` being assigned if you're calling getter methods with null arguments?

Comment: i didn't include those functions are working correctly

Comment: Why do you think that no value is inserted?

Answer (score -1):

try close(); and then openToWrite(); before inserting new record.

```
public void insertNotification(String type, String text){

openToWrite();
try {
    mSqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notification");
    String tableQuery = "CREATE TABLE "+ Constants.TABLE_NOTIFICATION + " ( " +
        Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            Constants.KEY_LAW_ID + " INT, " +
        Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TEXT + " VARCHAR, " +
        Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TIME + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " +
        Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_STATUS + " VARCHAR " +
        ")";
    mSqLiteDatabase.execSQL(tableQuery);
}

catch(Exception e){
    exceptionHandler.alert(e, "insertNotification()");
}

try {
close();
openToWrite();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TYPE, type);
    contentValues.put(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TEXT, text);
    contentValues.put(Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_STATUS, "unread");

    mSqLiteDatabase.insert(Constants.TABLE_NOTIFICATION, null, contentValues);
}

catch(Exception e){
    exceptionHandler.alert(e, "insertNotification()");
}
close();
```

}